# Impersonated User unauthorized in Google Analytics API, using Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google's PHP API Client, release 1.1.6.

We have a company Google account which controls our many Google Analytics account as well as our Google Developer apps.

I'm working on an app accessing our Google Analytics, using a Service Account set-up. I'm using the same code provided here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority

```
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key,
    'notasecret',                                 
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
    $user_to_impersonate,
);
```

In this case $client_email is the App Service Account client (random-chars@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and $user_to_impersonate is our company's Google Account.

As of a couple days ago this was all working correctly, and I could access all our Google Analytics accounts through the API after the above authentication. As of yesterday, I'm getting this error:

```
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}'
```

With the $user_to_impersonate parameter removed the authenticated works without error. However, I've been using the $user_to_impersonate as we have several hundred GA accounts and the Service Account client is not a permitted user on them (and would have a limit of 200 accounts anyway).

I couldn't find any recent updates to the way Google Dev's authentication works, but maybe I'm missing something.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Apparently this was a temporary error with Google's overall API, and is now fixed:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/891

**UPDATE 2:** Wasn't a temporary issues after all. The solution, if others need, is listed here. Basically giving your app perpetual access to the given account/scope.
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/801#issuecomment-171417538

Answer (score -1):

Google probably changed the handling of service accounts and this doesn't work anymore. It's not related to specific Google API client (PHP) nor specific API (Analytics), but it seems to me as a general change which affects everything.